# R - column with list of strings to vector of binary and back

Tags: r, dataframe

i have this code

```
dataframe = data.frame(nam= c("stefy, dany", "dany, ari", "ale"), num = c(1,2,3))
dim(dataframe)

library(qdapTools)

dataframe$nam = gsub(" ", "", dataframe$nam, fixed = TRUE)
names1 = mtabulate(  strsplit(dataframe$nam, ','))
names1
myNames = names(names1) # 29 total Genre
myNames


dataframe$nam = apply( names1 , 1 , paste , collapse = "," )

dataframe
```

The data looks like this

From

```
         nam num
1 stefy,dany   1
2   dany,ari   2
3        ale   3
```

To

```
  ale ari dany stefy
1   0   0    1     1
2   0   1    1     0
3   1   0    0     0

> myNames = names(names1)
> myNames
[1] "ale"   "ari"   "dany"  "stefy"
```

To

```
      nam num
1 0,0,1,1   1
2 0,1,1,0   2
3 1,0,0,0   3
```

is there a quick way to associated the binary vector/ Indicator Variables to the dictionary of the possible values back.
Also if i want to create a plot i want to see the string not the binary vectors
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using `dataframe` in the Note at the end this creates a 0/1 table:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

tab <- dataframe %>% 
            separate_rows(nam) %>% 
            table
```

giving:

```
> tab
   nam
num ale ari dany stefy
  1   0   0    1     1
  2   0   1    1     0
  3   1   0    0     0
```

and this reverses it:

```
tab %>% 
    as.data.frame %>% 
    filter(Freq != 0) %>% 
    select(-Freq) %>% 
    mutate(nam = as.character(nam)) %>% 
    nest(nam, .key = "nam")
```

giving:

```
  num         nam
1   3         ale
2   2   ari, dany
3   1 dany, stefy
```

### Note

The input used above is:

```
dataframe <- structure(list(nam = structure(c(3L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("ale", 
"dany, ari", "stefy, dany"), class = "factor"), num = c(1, 2, 
3)), .Names = c("nam", "num"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: is there a way to use some sort of multiplication of the vector `c(0,0,1,1)` to the `myNames ("ale"   "ari"   "dany"  "stefy")` to switch back a forth?  that should produce `( "day","stefy" ) ` .

Comment: `myNames[c(0, 0, 1, 1) == 1]` gives that subset of names.

Comment: if I have the data frame like  `nam num
1 0,0,1,1   1
2 0,1,1,0   2
3 1,0,0,0   3`   how can i plot  `dataframe

qplot(x=num, y =nam, data = dataframe)` and change the y to the original values of   `nam num
1 stefy,dany   1
2   dany,ari   2
3        ale   3`

Comment: i am having problem with the formatting of the comment. What i want to say is that if i transform the dataframe to the last one of my question and i want to plot it. How can i map the binary vector of the Y to the original values? thank you so much